# How do i increase the transaction result text in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Every time i run a transaction with multiple queries through phpMyAdmin the transaction result text box cuts off and I can't see rows affected for bottom queries.

How do i increase the size of the displayed text?

**Example:**
Here is dummy example of a result text and it cutting off:

`START TRANSACTION;`

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE col=value;# 3220 rows affected.`

`UPDATE table SET col = newvalue WHERE col=oldvalue;# 120 rows affected.`

`UPDATE table2 SET col2 = newvalue2 WHERE co[...]`

Notice how the last query has an elipsis and the rows affected cuts off.

Comment: At some point you'll want to use a better tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench) which is also free.

Comment: @tadman MySQL Workbench is not web-based. Often, host providers do not give a direct access to their MySQL server and you need to use a web-based product.

Comment: @MarcDelisle The Workbench tool supports SSH mode, which is how any decent provider provides remote access. If they don't provide remote access at all, they're a provider you'd want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the MaxCharactersInDisplayedSQL setting as documented in : https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxCharactersInDisplayedSQL